# Is there a standard design pattern for viewing + editing a record in React / Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Frequently I have a record of data to display to the user, and I want to display an `Edit` button allowing that data to be modified:

```
Create Pizza:

  sauce:  Margherita
  cheese: Gorgonzola
  radius: 12

[EDIT] [ORDER]
```

Is there a standard pattern for this in React / Material-UI? It seems silly to implement the same view twice, once with (readonly) `<div>`s or whatever and once with `<input>`s. Is there a better way? (Perhaps there's a Material-UI component with an `"editable"` prop, for instance.)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [api for text field](https://mui.com/api/text-field/). You'll see that you have a couple of ways of doing what you are looking.

1. You could set `disabled={true}`
2. You also get [inputProps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attributes), as an example

   `<TextField id="time" type="time" inputProps={{ readOnly:true }} />`

All the other elements should also have one or the other or both.

I usually have a wrapper component that accepts props such as `({isReadOnly: boolean})` & within that is the "native" React MUI component & then I send back editable or a read only component back to the caller.

EDIT:

```
interface MyTextFieldProps extends StandardTextFieldProps {
  isEditable?: boolean;
  // send in any other props necessary to render your non editable
  // portion
}

const MyTextField: FC<MyTextFieldProps> = (props) => {
  const { isEditable, ...other } = props;
  return <>{props.isEditable ? <TextField {...other}></TextField> : <span>text:{props.value}</span>}</>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Sangeet -- unfortunately, if I'm not mistaken, the input with both `disabled` and `readOnly` props still looks like an input element, not just a piece of static text. I'm looking for a solution that just looks like plain text when not in edit mode.

Comment: @Sasgorilla see my edit, this is the approach I usually take in my projects. But, there is nothing that I know of that Material UI provides natively to mimic what I've done in a few lines of code. You can pass any additional props say for styling etc.

Comment: Thanks @Sangeet, looks like I'll go ahead with this approach. I like the label on `TextField`, so I was hoping there was an easy way to use that while making it visually clear that the field is not editable, but looks like I'll just have to re-create that effect on my own. This seems like a pretty common design pattern, though, so I'm a little surprised there's not something more standard for it.